# Why do you want your Angular app to work offline?

Tags: angular, service-worker

I am deep into the Complete Angular course by Max S. on Udemy and we are talking about service workers now. I am really wondering why you would ever want your Angular (or any other) app to work offline?

Can someone help explain this to me, so I can make an informed decision to try and understand the lecture?

Comment: The purpose is not neccessarily to work offline all the time but by caching pages to offer a robust experience where if you are not connected or are on a shaky connection you still receive some basic content. It also offers a fast first page.

Comment: Using less mobile data is also a topic here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mainly to improve user experience.

It will help when connection is unstable and serve some basic content even when disconnected for a while. 
Example could be when we want to create Progress Web App. About them you can read here https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/.

User could add such an app to his/her phones home screen and then we want to serve some basic functionality without the internet connection.

For more, you can read about offline first approach https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/offline-first